# How to use the multiple select sum() queries in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `challan` which is working for fee challan.

But now I want to show the dues which is received by the help the of four queries.

And I want to add to add that two in my `challan` stored procedure:

```
create proc [dbo].[challan]
    @sessionid int,
    @month nvarchar(20)
as
    select distinct 
        student.Student_id as [A/c #], student.Student_Name, 
        parent.father_name, class.class_numeric, invoice.Fee_description, 
        invoice.Amount, invoice.issue_date, invoice.month 
    from 
        student
    join 
        parent on student.father_nic = parent.father_nic
    join 
        allocate_class on student.Student_id = allocate_class.Student_id
    join 
        class on class.class_id = allocate_class.class_id
    join 
        session on allocate_class.session_id = session.session_id
    join 
        invoice on student.Student_id = invoice.Student_id
    where 
        session.session_id = @sessionid 
        and student.status = 'active' 
        and invoice.month = @month
    order by 
        class.class_numeric asc
```

This query is used to collect the current month fee which will be subtracted from the dues because it has already shown in the `challan`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(invoice.Amount) 
FROM 
    invoice 
WHERE 
    invoice.month = 'November-2019' 
    AND invoice.Student_id = '115'
```

Now I run two another which is used form the sum of the student of all `challan` in the invoice table from which i have to minus the current month fee

```
SELECT SUM(invoice.Amount) 
FROM invoice 
WHERE invoice.Student_id = '115
```

This is used to sum all the received fee of a student in receipt table:

```
SELECT SUM(Recipt.Paid_amount) 
FROM Recipt 
WHERE Recipt.Student_id = '115'
```

Now the problem is to minus the 3) query from above 1) and two) query and then put in the last of `challan` stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE condition for achieving the same

```
    select 
    student.Student_id as [A/c #], student.Student_Name, parent.father_name,class.class_numeric, invoice.Fee_description, invoice.Amount, invoice.          issue_date, invoice.month ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN invoice.month = 'November-2019' AND invoice.Student_id = '115' THEN invoice.Amount ELSE 0 END)
from student
join parent on student.father_nic = parent.father_nic
join allocate_class on student.Student_id = allocate_class.Student_id
join class on class.class_id = allocate_class.class_id
join session on allocate_class.session_id = session.session_id
join invoice on student.Student_id = invoice.Student_id
where session.session_id=  @sessionid AND student.status = 'active' AND invoice.month = @month
order by class.class_numeric asc
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'student.Student_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: select 
   
    SUM(CASE WHEN invoice.month = 'November-2019' AND invoice.Student_id = '115' THEN invoice.Amount ELSE 0 END)
from student
join parent on student.father_nic = parent.father_nic
join allocate_class on student.Student_id = allocate_class.Student_id
join class on class.class_id = allocate_class.class_id
join session on allocate_class.session_id = session.session_id
join invoice on student.Student_id = invoice.Student_id
where session.session_id=  <@sessionid> AND student.status = 'active' AND invoice.month = @month

Comment: bro it has the same worked as the query number which i already mention..

Comment: my is to make one query from the above three queries or a store procedure in which there are multiple queries used