# How to search urdu text in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, urdu

There is no problem inserting urdu text into SQL Server, but I have a problem searchig for urdu text - I keep getting:

```
0 rows effect
```

and text (which I want to search) is already in the SQL Server database.

This is my code:

```
con.Open();

string Query = "Select vendor.VendorID from vendor where vendor.Vendor_Name ='" + textBox4.Text + "'";

SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SDA.Fill(dt);

vend_id = (dt.Rows[0][0]).ToString();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing `N` before string literals makes them unicode in SQL Server. You can do this like:

```
string Query = "Select vendor.VendorID from vendor where vendor.Vendor_Name =N'" + textBox4.Text + "'";
```

But this is prone to SQL Injection attacks. Please use parametrized queries that will handle unicode as well. Like this:

```
string Query = "Select vendor.VendorID from vendor where vendor.Vendor_Name =@Name";
//...
SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox4.Text);
```

Comment: ok but in 2nd query you don't use the N keyword where i have to put in the 2nd query

Comment: Yes. Only string literals (i.e. `'abc'`) require the `N` unicode identifier. If you do it by parameters then it's handled automatically. That's one of the upsides of the second approach

Comment: ok thanks bro but plz see my another question "How to use the multiple select sum() query in store procedure"

Comment: Do you want to search? As in you want to return `abcd` when input is `ab`?

Comment: its done bro by your help.. i was accessing the id of a specific vendor which is written in urdu text

Comment: and can you please give fb id or something else if you want and don't because you're good

Comment: Thanks. Ask anything you want here. This way others with same issues as you would get this results as well. Also by asking more and better questions you establish your reputation as well.

Comment: and please see this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298734/how-to-use-the-multiple-select-sum-queries-in-store-procedure

Comment: than you so much once again

Comment: And **even better** if you've check this out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...